# Prompting a Custom Web Page When User Taps My Card on iPhone (Wallet, Contactless)

Tags: iphone, contactless-smartcard, apple-wallet

I want to develop a ticket that can be added to apple wallet and used with iPhone contactless flow.
When the user taps this ticket, I would like him to choose whether the access is for one person or more (there could be different options for different users).
I would like to intercept the flow with my custom page so the user can choose from the options they have.

Is this possible?

Thank you!